# How to make all the project in my solution to have same product version on shared assemblyVersion ?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I using share reference to AssemblyInfo.cs between all projects in the solution and i set the AssemblyVersion to be ("1.0.*")

This each project output file ( dll/exe ) contain **different** File Version.

I want to have this file version **same** on all the assemblies and not different like i have now.

But i want to use the same default build number ( using ("1.0.*") )

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my solution this was achieved by creating the separate assembly info file (let's call it GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs) and adding it to each project in the solution as reference. You should remove assembly attributes from each AssemblyInfo.cs file though.

```
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Company name")]

[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Revision and Build  Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.9.0.24850")]
```

When you're adding an existing item to a project you have option on the 'Add' button 'Add as a link'.